# FormBuilder( BackDrop CMS) ... how to add fields?

Tags: custom-fields, forms, formbuilder

Evaluating CiviCMS for a non-profit. Looks like lots of good features!
Trying to make some custom forms for volunteers to fill out online.
I made a custom field set, populated with lots of fields. The field set previews perfectly. But ***How*** can I get it to integrate into the form created in Form Builder??

IF I use the + tab, and add a case, I can then find the various fields in the select dropdown list. But adding them doesn't put them onto the form, it just adds them to the column to the left...

Are there docs for this module somewhere?? I've seen it described as a "UI" but it's not the kind of UI I was expecting...

Comment: We use a lot of forms on our website - but they are all made through the very mature and proven Drupal Webform, along with the equally proven and well supported CiviCRM Webform module.  I am not sure what CMS you are using, but I'd go for that if you are on Drupal until the new Forms and Search kit are where they need to be.  It'll come, but not yet I feel.

Always tell people what versions of Civi and your underlying CMS are - it really helps!

Good luck with CiviCRM - its great :-)

Comment: FormBuilder doesnt seem to work - and doesnt look anything like the videos! Using 1.23.1 Backdrop CMS, and CiviCRM 5.57.1.  -  so will try looking for WebForm module. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!

You should be able to drag the custom fields from the left on to the form and then set relevant options on them.

There are some docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/creating-new-forms/ but FormBuilder is evolving rapidly and the documentation may not be completely up to date.  There are also a few relevant videos on https://www.youtube.com/@CiviCRM-project

You can also ask questions about FormBuilder on the ~FormBuilder channel on https://chat.civicrm.org

Comment: hmmm.. that's how i expected it would work... but it's not possible to drag any fields over!

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in your browser console?

Comment: AH, that's a good point, and I didn't even look at that. I actually moved on to use WebForms instead - which provided a few challenges to get set up ( like making sure all the dependencies were in, and setting the max_php_inputs to a higher number  -  was puzzled why my changes were not taking until I figured out that I had to explicitly restart the php-fpm... just restarting httpd wasn't doing it!). Anyway, "drupal7" WebForms seems to be working great in BackDrop CMS, will revisit the CiviCRM one later on (as time permits)

Comment: One note of warning!  We are currently migrating from Drupal 7 to Drupal 10.  Webforms (and Views if you are using them with your forms) created in Drupal 7 will not just port over!! So be careful about getting a head of steam on Webforms that you will need to port when Drupal 7 goes Enf of Life in November this year

Comment: Right, webforms in Drupal 10 are not compatible with Drupal 7 webforms, but Backdrop webforms are a continuation of Drupal 7 webforms.   But I wouldn't start anything new with webforms unless you're sure FormBuilder can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... running BackDrop CMS is essentially a sort of port of Drupal 7, so WebForms is working nicely, and probably should run OK forever . Sadly BackDrop "CiviCRM" development as a whole seems to be almost abandoned!! I have the latest CiviCRM version but its littered with PHP8 warnings and some PHP8 errors and thus even some bugs ( like some configuration pages will not accept the changes).
Kind of dragging to an unfortunate  halt with this, as I have no desire to play with Drupal 8/9/10/+ and its 'composer hell' :(